# Storing Log info using log4net

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, log4net

How to store log in MySql database using log4net

Comment: How to "overwrite existing log file" ??? I have tried to set attribute property  <appendToFile value="false" />. but still log file is not getting overwrite. 
please let me know where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/using-postsharp-and-log4net-to-set-up-co) blog is exactly what you are looking for